# Is there a Python optimization package for non linear and non scalar target functions

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking to solve problems with the following characteristics:

```
max {x * max (f(var_1),f(var_2)) + y * min (f(var_3),f(var_4)) + ...}
s.t.
b_0 <= x <= b_1
c_0 <= y <= c_1
d_0 <= var_1 <= d_1
d_2 <= var_2 <= d_3
d_4 <= var_3 <= d_5
d_6 <= var_4 <= d_7
```

etc...

using python.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to include what `f` is, what `...` is and what `non-scalar target functions` are.

Comment: Take a look at [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Comment: scipy.optimize can't handle target functions that consist of max {} or min {} - that's also what I meant by non-scalar.

Comment: f(var_1) = 100 + var_1, for example

Comment: `max (f(var_1),f(var_2))` can be interpreted as just `g(f(var_1),f(var_2))` unless you have some multi-level model in mind. Again, the question needs a lot of editing to make some  sense.

Comment: agree. I can simplify: max {(x * max(100-z,0) + y*max(0,150-z)}; s.t.-100<=x<=100,-100<=y<=100,80<=z<=150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve this kind of problems using [CasADi](https://web.casadi.org/) software, please follow this instruction (https://web.casadi.org/get/) to install the package into your computer

Here, I provide you to how to solve your problem, you may change the functions (f1,..f4) and values as you want.

```
    from casadi import *

    x = SX.sym('x')
    y = SX.sym('y')
    var_1 = SX.sym('var_1')
    var_2 = SX.sym('var_2')
    var_3 = SX.sym('var_3')
    var_4 = SX.sym('var_4')

    f1 = x + var_1 -y
    f2 = x + var_2 -y
    f3 = var_3*x
    f4 = var_4-y

    obj = fmax(f1, f2) + y*fmin(f3,f4)

    opt_val = vertcat(x, y, var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4)
    nlp_prob = {'f':obj, 'x':opt_val, 'p':[]}

    opts = {}
    opts["expand"] = True
    opts["ipopt.max_iter"] = 100
    opts["ipopt.tol"] = 1e-4
    opts["ipopt.print_level"] = 0
    opts["print_time"] = 1
    opts["ipopt.acceptable_tol"] = 1e-8

    solver = nlpsol('solver', 'ipopt', nlp_prob, opts)

    lbx = DM(opt_val.size1(),1)
    ubx = DM(opt_val.size1(),1)

    lbx[0] = -100 #b_0
    lbx[1] = -100 #c_0
    lbx[2] = -100 #d_0
    lbx[3] = -100 #d_2
    lbx[4] = -100 #d_4
    lbx[5] = -100 #d_6

    ubx[0] = 500 #b_1
    ubx[1] = 500 #c_1
    ubx[2] = 500 #d_1
    ubx[3] = 500 #d_3
    ubx[4] = 500 #d_5
    ubx[5] = 500 #d_7


    # initial values for x,y, val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4
    x0 = DM([[3],[6],[34],[3],[23],[25]])

    args = {'lbx':lbx, 'ubx':ubx, 'lbg':-inf, 'ubg':inf, 'p':[], 'x0':x0}
    sol = solver(**args)

    print("======Solution=====")
    sol = sol['x'].full().flatten()
    print("x: ", sol[0])
    print("y: ", sol[1])
    print("val_1: ", sol[2])
    print("val_2: ", sol[3])
    print("val_3: ", sol[4])
    print("val_4: ", sol[5])
```

Expected output

```
======Solution=====
('x: ', 3.0756501068719735)
('y: ', -99.999974650383308)
('val_1: ', -98.442843531628299)
('val_2: ', 108.68842844611186)
('val_3: ', 195.0797522765082)
('val_4: ', 499.99687090550719)
```

Let me know anything is not clear

Comment: I believe this is a bad solution. Not even close to optimal. Of course, that makes sense as you are solving a non-convex problem with a local solver.

Comment: @erwin-kalvelagen Why do you think this is a bad solution?

Comment: Not close to optimal. (It is feasible).

Comment: @erwin-kalvelagen I do understand what you mean if you have a  better solution why dont you post it? Yeap, if I know the objective function exactly, I could define it appropriately

Comment: Try `x0 = DM([[-100],[500],[-100],[-100],[500],[-100]])`. Orders of magitude difference.

Comment: Can you suggest a model to reach these solutions ?

Comment: @Rani I didn't get what you mean by a model here

Comment: I meant if you are familiar with a package that provides a model to solve these kind of problems

Comment: https://web.casadi.org/ but you have to formulate your problem your own